# Possible leaks when using Analyze-tool. No leaks while running instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

As the title describes it.

We have an application that atm shows three possible leaks when using the Analyze-tool. Yet there are no leaks what so ever when running the instruments to check for leaks.

Do we have to take care of the false-positives that show up using the Analyze-tool?

EDIT:

```
    aViewcontroller *anotherViewController = [[aViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"aViewController" bundle:nil];

    anotherViewController.foo = bar;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewcontroller animated:YES];

    [anotherViewcontroller release];
```

While not having the release, we get false positives, and if we have the release we get actual leaks while running the instruments.

Comment: Without any code its almost impossible to guess why the analyze tool is showing leak. Are you sure that this is a false-positive, that is you are not making any mistake while using instrument? May be the leak condition is not occurring while you are testing.

Comment: We have a very small application at the time being, as we can only go between three different views and call an nsxmlparser basically, so we have tested every combination of possible outcomes and there are no leaks if we comment out the release. If we have the release, we get actual leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaks wont show leaks unless you perform the absolute exact order of events to reproduce the leak.

Read the code that analyse has pointed out and carefully check what the count should be, its usually pretty good at finding simple issues, but in the event you're doing something a bit different it may show you some false positives.

Answer (score 0):

In *most* cases, you can avoid false positives by improving your code and take care of how you note it down. If you give us more information, maybe we can give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks! Where does anotherViewController come from? Anyway: I can't imagine why Instruments will show a leak when you release the controller.

Comment: Added some more code. We also have no idea why the instruments gives us leaks.